# Will a VM in VirtualBox crash, if I spend too much ram on other app in host OS?

Tags: virtualbox

guest OS won't boot if the freed memory is too low, but what if it boots, and then I accidentally use too much memory on host OS on other app, will the guest OS crash?

Comment: It could in theory.  Of course that shouldn't be possible since `VirtualBox` should be reserving the amount of memory it needs.

Comment: @Ramhound You mean VirtualBox automatically lock the memory it needs, so I don't need to worry about if it will crash or not right?

Comment: The word "lock" isn't the correct word in this case.  All the same you shouldn't worry about it.  If your system starts to run out of virtual memory then the operating system will inform you of that problem before `VirtualBox` is aware of it.